# How to take picture with blur background using FujiFilm HS10

Tags: depth-of-field, blur, fujifilm

I tried a lot to take portrait pictures with blur background using my FujiFilm HS10 but haven't succeeded yet. I use f2.8 but still cannot get the effect. Can any of the experts give me any suggestion.

Comment: And a bunch of other duplicates as well.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to realize that depth of field depends in part on the distance to the subject. Even at large apertures (low numbers like f/2.8), the depth of field will be much greater if you focus on something far away than if your subject is close to the camera.

So, if your goal is a portrait with a soft background, get relatively close to the subject and use a large aperture like the f/2.8 setting that you're trying. If you want the background to be very blurry, increase the distance between subject and background.